# Using sed with minus sign

Tags: sed

I want to find all instances of `#- "${COMPOSER_CONFIG}` and replace with `- "${COMPOSER_CONFIG}` within a file. (Note, the removal of `#-` )

The command I have come up with is:

```
sed -i '/#- "${COMPOSER_CONFIG}/- "${COMPOSER_CONFIG}' docker-compose.yml
```

But I get the error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 25: unknown command: `-'
```

It appears the minus sign is causing the issue. After researching this I am unable to identify why this is the case.

Any insight greatly welcome.

Comment: So, why not use substitution command? `sed -i 's/#- "${COMPOSER_CONFIG}/- "${COMPOSER_CONFIG}/g' docker-compose.yml`

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: @Cyrus I have tried to improve the question.

Comment: If you previously downvoted my question, please reconsider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
sed -i '/COMPOSER_CONFIG/s/#//' docker-compose.yml
```